# Getting type error when trying to use operator methods in Python

Tags: python, operators

I have a problem using operator methods in a more extensive python script. To narrow down the problem I created the following example code.

```
class Car:
   def __init__(self, Name, Speed):
      self.Name = Name
      self.Speed = Speed
      self.PrintText()

   def PrintText(self):
      print("My %s runs %s km/h." % (self.Name, self.Speed))

   def GetName(self):
      return self.Name

   def GetSpeed(self):
      return self.Speed

   def __sub__(self, other):
      try: # Try with assumption that we have to deal with an instance of AnotherClass
         a = self.GetSpeed()
      except: # If it doesn't work let's assume we have to deal with a float
         a = self

      try: # Try with assumption that we have to deal with an instance of AnotherClass
         b = other.GetSpeed()
      except: # If it doesn't work let's assume we have to deal with a float
         b = other

      return a - b

Car1 = Car("VW", 200.0)
Car2 = Car("Trabant", 120.0)
print("")

Difference = Car1 - Car2
print("The speed difference is %g km/h." % Difference)
print("")

Difference = Car2 - 6.0
print("My %s is %g km/h faster than a pedestrian." % (Car2.GetName(), Difference))
print("")

Difference = 250.0 - Car1
print("I wish I had a car that is %g km/h faster than the %s." % (Difference, Car1.GetName()))
```

The Output is:

```
My VW runs 200.0 km/h.
My Trabant runs 120.0 km/h.

The speed difference is 80 km/h.

My Trabant is 114 km/h faster than a pedestrian.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 41, in <module>
    Difference = 250.0 - Car1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'instance'
```

How could I solve the problem that arises when the first object is a float?

Comment: you need `__rsub__`

Comment: The answer below is correct. I just want to give advice. You can use the `__str__` method instead of the PrintText function. Then you can type like this: `print(Car)`

Answer (score 1):

you need to define substraction with reversed operands (the code itself was fixed // your question, but probably needs more cleaning):

```
   def __rsub__(self, other):
        a = self.GetSpeed()

        try: # Try with assumption that we have to deal with an instance of AnotherClass
         b = other.GetSpeed()
        except AttributeError: # If it doesn't work let's assume we have to deal with a float
         b = other

        return b - a
```

now your output:

```
My VW runs 200.0 km/h.
My Trabant runs 120.0 km/h.

The speed difference is 80 km/h.

My Trabant is 114 km/h faster than a pedestrian.

I wish I had a car that is 50 km/h faster than the VW.
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your specific question, but it would be a lot simpler and cleaner to subtract actual *speeds* to *speeds*, not *cars* to *speeds*.
Just do `car1.Speed() - car2.Speed()` or `car2.Speed() - 6.0`. Otherwise you create your own problem.

As a side note I also suggest you to follow Python style guide https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/